# Вывод списка пользователей без дубликатов

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Есть список пользователей (формируется по дате последнего захода на сайт). В начале выводится 40 карточек, далее информация подзагружается через AJAX (используя OFFSET в таблице с пользователями).

Проблема в том, что при высокой посещаемости структура списка обновляется в промежутке между первой и последующей загрузкой, и выводятся дубликаты.

Есть идея при первой загрузке записывать в JSON-массив ID по первой 1000 элементов и при последующих загрузках выводить информацию уже по этим ID. Либо сразу загружать данные по первой 1000 пользователей, далее выводить их без дополнительных запросов (например, как это делают vk или instagram). В обоих случаях ограничивать выдачу первой 1000 пользователей (этого должно хватить для полноценного выбора, если недостаточно - делается запрос с уточняющими параметрами).

К сожалению, трюк с LAST_ID здесь не прокатит, т.к. в таблице не список постов или другой информации, которая привязана к временной метке или схожему якорю.

Кто знает более элегантное и простое решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте таблицу `дата последнего захода на сайт` с полями `id`, `user_id`, `timestamp`. Поле `user_id` - уникально и ссылается на таблицу пользователей. При необходимости обновить время - стираете старую запись и добавляете новую. Так Вы получаете наращиваемый `id`

Еще вариант - делать повторный запрос не по смещению, а по условию, что время у вновь выбранных записей меньше либо равно, чем у последней выведенной записи. А на клиенте отфильтруете одну-две записи, которые уже были выведены.

Почему `меньше либо равно`? Потому, что если делать строго меньше, то можно пропустить записи с одинаковым временем из которых одна попала в предыдущую выборку, а вторая нет